# What does the WHATWG working standard mean by the note "At the time of writing, no such rules actually exist"?

Tags: html, xml-parsing, xhtml

Reading the WHATWG living standard I found this note in 13.2 Parsing XHTML documents.

> An XML parser, for the purposes of this specification, is a construct
>   that follows the rules given in the XML specification to map a string
>   of bytes or characters into a Document object.
>
> *Note: At the time of writing, no such rules actually exist.*

And the word **Document** links to the HTML DOM Document (the thing that has a `title` and a collection of `forms`, etc.)

It appears to entirely undermine the purpose of the definition above it, and thereby all of section 13.2 that depends on that definition. Is there a more subtle way of interpreting it?

(To avoid this being an open-ended philosophical question, I am specifically interested in what is known about the WHATWG author's opinions, e.g. quotes from (and links to) supporting blog posts would be great.)

Answer (score 0):

Ian Hickson, author/editor of said living standard has said

["I’m probably most proud of the HTML parser specification"](http://html5doctor.com/interview-with-ian-hickson-html-editor/)

It's a state machine for converting a `text/html` input stream to a DOM document. The normative part of the quoted text is acknowledging the fact that for the XHTML syntax, the equivalent rules are the responsibility of the XML spec.

The nature of XML though, is that the parsing can be inferred from XML syntax definition alone, so the XML spec doesn't define the precise parsing rules in anything like the same fashion. So the note is saying, "don't bother looking for them, because they're not there".

Other than that, it doesn't matter. Implementors don't seem to have any difficulty implementing XML parsers interoperably, so everything works nicely.

If that doesn't satisfy you, try just asking him directly. The [WHATWG IRC](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/IRC) is a good place to start.

Comment: Actually, this is wrong. The problem is that while XML defines parsing, it does not define parsing a byte stream into DOM tree. It just defines parsing into a rather conceptual XML tree, but how that corresponds to DOM nodes is not defined.

Comment: @Anne - Thanks, makes sense. Surely the mapping between the conceptual XML tree and DOM nodes ought to be the responsibility of the DOM spec, don't you think?

Comment: Well, HTML handles it for HTML. I would think XML should handle it for XML. Note also that it cannot be a simple mapping, since `<script>` will execute synchronously during parsing. So it needs to be actually defined as part of the parse operation if you want to define all the details.